# Hello, please how can i solve this problem? Also define the standard property 'transition' for compatibilitycss

Tags: css

please how can i solve this problem, I'm trying to combine some styles with the CSS, but suddenly I get this error.show me an error with this mesage: Also define the standard property 'transition' for compatibilitycss
Shorthand property combines four of the transition properties into a single property.

```
.mod-type-box .item .label{
    font-size:24px;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-family: 'TencentSansw7';
    margin-bottom: 8px;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in;
```